# how to add data into nsmutable array with a new key?

Tags: json, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

i am new in iphone development.recently i start a project.after JSON parsing i got a

```
NSmutablearray
(
    {
    "contest_description" = "  ";
    "contest_id" = 245;
    "contest_name" = "teating1 ";
    "contest_status" = Running;
    "creator_id" = "1716091396 ";
    "end_time" = "2012-10-26 04:10:25";
    "full_name" = "Adit Hasan ";
    "no_of_contestants" = 3;
    "no_of_days" = 5;
    "start_time" = "2012-10-21 04:10:24";
    "time_stamp" = "2012-10-24 04:11:09";
    "winner_user_id" = "Not Yet";
    },
    {
    "contest_description" = "  ";
    "contest_id" = 248;
    "contest_name" = "hhhhhhk ";
    "contest_status" = Running;
    "creator_id" = "1716091396 ";
    "end_time" = "2012-10-25 13:33:35";
    "full_name" = "Adit Hasan ";
    "no_of_contestants" = 2;
    "no_of_days" = 4;
    "start_time" = "2012-10-21 13:33:34";
    "time_stamp" = "2012-10-23 13:35:09";
    "winner_user_id" = "Not Yet";
    },
)
```

How to add new key like `updated_image` and assign a value to this key?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`, I don't know if it is `Mutable` that is why I am referring them as normal NS immutable classes, if they are not mutable, you need to convert them to `Mutable` objects. Like follows

`NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:yourPreviousArray];`

`NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:previousDictionary];`

Any how, this is what I think solution for your problem is, am considering the already existing arrays(doesn't really matter if its not, as long as you are not adding new dictionaries into it) and dictionaries to be mutable.

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in previousArray) {
    [dictionary setValue:updated_image forKey:@"updated_image"];
}
```

If you want to set value of the new key `updated_image` later, initialize it as `NULL` and set it later.

Why don't you give a good read of following

[NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray)

[NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary)

[NSMutableDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

And also the sample programs there.